How to make LazyVerticalGrid scrollable on Android TV?
I'm aware that TVLazyVerticalGrid is deprecated and I've been trying to use LazyVerticalGrid. I can't understand how can I scroll by items in list one by one using dpad and TV remote.
I expect the list to be scrolled one by one item, but it's not. I need something like this: https://joebirch.co/wp-content/uploads/2023/07/gridddd.png
@Composable
fun AnimalsGrid(
    animalUiModelList: ImmutableList<AnimalUiModel>,
    isLoading: Boolean,
    onLastAnimalVisible: () -> Unit,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    val lazyGridState = rememberLazyGridState()

    val itemWidth = 468.dp / 2.5f
    val itemHeight = 225.dp / 2.5f
    val itemSpacing = 10.dp
    var isItemInFocus by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
 

    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(3),
        state = lazyGridState,
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(itemSpacing),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(itemSpacing),
        userScrollEnabled = true,
        modifier = modifier
            .clip(RoundedCornerShape(12.dp))
            .background(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.surface)
            .padding(16.dp)
            .fillMaxSize()

    ) {
        items(animalsUiModelList.size) { index ->
            val animals = animalsUiModelList[index]
            Animal(
                animalModel = animal,
                modifier = Modifier
                    .width(itemWidth)
                    .height(itemHeight)
                    .focusable()
                    .onFocusChanged { isItemInFocus = it.isFocused }
                    .background(if(isItemInFocus) Color.Green else Color.Transparent)
            )
        }

        if (isLoading) {
            item {
                CircularProgressIndicator(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(20.dp)
                        .size(24.dp),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.onSurface,
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


Move the focusable modifier below onFocusChanged.
